# How Do You Make a Permanent File in Python Using Code? - Repl.it

Tags: python, file, save, replit

I am trying to use code to make two files for every new person that uses my program. So far I have:

```
import os
playeritems = 'PlayerFiles/PlayerItems'
playergold = 'PlayerFiles/PlayerGold'
file_number = '7'
with open(os.path.join(playeritems, "inventory.%s.txt" % file_number), "w") as f, open(os.path.join(playergold, "gold.%s.txt" % file_number), "w") as g:
    #do stuff
with open(os.path.join(playeritems, "inventory.%s.txt" % file_number), "r"):
    #Fails to find the file.
```

But after this code runs, the files no longer exist. How do I make it so that the files permanently exist after use? I looked at the website [that briefs you on files,](https://realpython.com/working-with-files-in-python/) but it didn't help. Thanks for your time and consideration!

> the error occurs on the second with-statement. file inventory.7.txt doesn't exist!

[The entire code, if you want to take a look.](https://repl.it/@FRASHERGRAY/Simplemmo-Crafting)

Comment: Hmm, the files should exist, are you sure there isn't anything else affecting the file in your code?

Comment: Why write to a file? Use sqlite. It is much simpler in the long run.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of response, I am trying to post a screen shot of my entire loop, but it takes up 2 pictures, and I cannot figure out how to put 2 in one question, or any in a comment.

Comment: What is sqlite? I need to write to the files because there has to be certain things in beginner files.

Comment: copy the actual text, rather than posting a picture.

Comment: @warped, I posted all of the code in the with-loop. I just realized that there is an `f.write` there that I don't want, but it shouldn't be affecting the current problem.

Comment: Can you re-open and read the files *before* your process exits?  Are you running this in some sort of (online?) sandbox that wouldn’t keep anything afterward?

Comment: @Davis Herring, I am using repl.it, which saves its files. What do you mean, process exits?

Comment: @FrasherGray: I wanted to know if you could `open` the file immediately after closing it before exiting the program/script.  (Technically a process is one run of a program.)

Comment: @Davis Herring, no I cannot. Once it is closed, it dissapears forever.

Comment: @FrasherGray: You should edit your question to demonstrate the shortest possible create-vanish interval; that should help debug it.

Comment: @DavisHerring, The shortest possible create-vanish interval is as soon as the loop ends.

Comment: What I mean is, it vanishes when the loop ends. So however short the loop is when it vanishes.

Comment: @FrasherGray: OK: now **edit** and include a minimal **reproducer** for that interval.  Don’t even write any text to the file unless that’s necessary to trigger the bug.

Comment: So just write the `with statement`? I don't understand. What is in the loop doesn't matter. Tested it with just opening the files. Doesn't save.

Comment: @FrasherGray: Show a program that creates a file, closes it, and then *fails* to re-open it for reading.  That way we can see the failure other than by “the files no longer exist”.

Comment: Actually, I have the program end immediately after it makes the files. (An attempt to fix the problem).

Comment: It won't let me edit this in, so @DavisHerring

Comment: @FrasherGray: That’s not what I said (several times), nor is it usable for debugging.

Comment: @DavisHerring, like that?

Comment: @FrasherGray: Closer.  Merge the two examples, use only one file if possible, use `pass` as a `with` body (if that works), and provide the error traceback.

Comment: Your entire code needs indentation formatting.

Comment: Why? It is fine the way it is.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://repl.it/repls/TechnologicalUpsetGoal

Comment: What? That looks like a perfect recreation.

Comment: @FrasherGray The files are written and can be read even after refresh.

Comment: Then @aaron there is something wrong with my directories, like I stated in my answer.

Comment: Please create a repro.

Comment: What is a repro?

Comment: Once the directories are created the code creates files. a repro may be a tpo of a repo(sitory) or a fulle example of working code, playergold is not defined in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the directory if not existing, `makedirs` creates all sub directories

```
import os
playeritems = 'PlayerFiles/PlayerItems'
playergold = 'PlayerFiles/PlayerGold'

#check if directory exists else create new
if not os.path.exists(playeritems):
    os.makedirs(playeritems)
if not os.path.exists(playergold):
    os.makedirs(playergold)

file_number = '7'
with open(os.path.join(playeritems, "inventory.%s.txt" % file_number), "w") as f, open(os.path.join(playergold, "gold.%s.txt" % file_number), "w") as g:
    #do stuff
with open(os.path.join(playeritems, "inventory.%s.txt" % file_number), "r"):
    #will  find the file
```

Answer (score 2):

I must have an issue with the directories, because

```
with open("inventory.%s.txt" % file_number, "w") as f, open("gold.%s.txt" % file_number, "w") as g:
```

makes the files permanently. I don't actually need the folders, so I can deal with no directories.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see here is that the directories in the given path of the file are not already there, and you are trying to create them dynamically with 'open' but, it is not possible to do so.

The way to solve this problem is to check if the file path really exists or not, if it exists then open file and if not then create directories and complete path.

For your example case, code will be like:

```
import os
playeritems = str(os.getcwd())+'/PlayerFiles/PlayerItems/'
playergold = str(os.getcwd())+'/PlayerFiles/PlayerGold/'
file_number = '7'

#check if PlayerItem path exist, if not create directories that are needed
if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(playeritems)):
    try:
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(playeritems))
        print("created PlayerItem path")
    except OSError as exc: 
        if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise
#check if PlayerGold Path exist, if not create directories that are needed
if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(playergold)):
    try:
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(playergold))
        print("created PlayerGold Path")
    except OSError as exc: 
        if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise

with open(os.path.join(playeritems, "inventory.%s.txt" % file_number), "w") as f, open(os.path.join(playergold, "gold.%s.txt" % file_number), "w") as g:
    #do stuff
    print("inventoryfile and goldfile created!")
with open(os.path.join(playeritems, "inventory.%s.txt" % file_number), "r"):
    #do Stuff
    print("Reopened playeritem inventory file")
```

Comment: I assure you the directories exist.

Comment: But you could be one to something. Is there something wrong with the way I am calling my directories?

Comment: Have you tried using backslash '\' instead of frontslash '/' in the path as you are using windows because this code works perfectly fine on my macOS?
If you haven't, you can do it by something like playergold=playergold.replace("/","\") and playeritems=playeritems.replace("/","\")

Comment: can you provide me with the console output with errors

Comment: It says that it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, this is definitely a problem with directories.

If a parent directory of a file doesn't exist, Python will refuse to create that file:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> my_dir = Path('directory_base')
>>> with open(my_dir / 'example.txt', 'w') as f:
>>>    f.write('Hi there!')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'directory_base\\example.txt'
```

This is easy enough to fix by creating the directory. `pathlib.Path` objects have a handy method called `mkdir()` to create any and all parent directories at once:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> my_dir = Path('directory_base')
>>> my_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
>>> with open(my_dir / 'example.txt', 'w') as f:
>>>    f.write('Hi there!')
>>> with open(my_dir / 'example.txt') as f:
>>>    print(f.read())

'Hi there!'
```

`parents=True` says that any and all parent directories should be created, and `exist_ok` says that if the directory already exists, Python should not throw an exception.

Comment: This gives me the error: `TypeError: Unsupported operand type for: % Poxispath and string` Edit: oh but you didn't make that with my code, so you wouldn't have gotten that error.